# Cards on the Table : Python 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, int, typeerror, iterable

When I test this code in iPython I receive a Type Error 'int' object is not iterable. specifically pointing to these lines of code ----->

```
from __future__ import print_function
import random

deck = ['2s', '3s', '4s', '5s', '6s', '7s', '8s', '9s', '10s', 'Js', 'Qs', 'Ks', 'As'] *#Set of cards*

def score_hand(hand): # defines the score of the individual cards and player total*
    score=0
    for card in hand:    # <------
        f = card[0]      # This seems to be where the problem is but I don't understand it*
        if f == 'A':     
            if score>=20:
                score += 1
            else:
                score +=11
        elif f == 'J' or f == 'Q' or f == 'K':   
            score += 10
        elif f == '1':   
            score += 10
        else:            
            score += int(f)    
    return score

def print_hand(hand):
    print('cards = ', end = ' ')
    for card in hand:
        print(card, end=' ')

score = score_hand(hand)
print('  score = ', score)

def check_bust(hand):
    score = score_hand(hand) # <------
    if score <= 21:
        return True
    if score > 21:
        return False

def blackjack():
    hand = []
    score = score_hand(hand)
    choice = 'h'
    if check_bust(score) == True: # <------
        if choice == 'h':     
            card_num = random.randint(0, len(deck)-1)
            card = deck[card_num]
            hand.append(card)
            deck.remove(deck[random])
            print_hand(hand)
            choice = raw_input("Enter h for hit or s for stand.")
            return check_bust(score)
        if choice == 's':
            print('compare with dealer')
    if check_bust(score)== False:
            print('Bust, score =',score)
             return
```

This is supposed to

1. assign the randomly selected card from the deck list a value
2. add that cards value to the players hand
3. remove said card from the deck list
4. Depending on the combined 'score' of the cards it should stop if the score exceeds 21.
5. If the score does not it should return to check_bust(score) and repeat until the player exceeds or enters 's' to stop.

I attempted to research the many similar questions on this site but found I could not understand. I want to know what is wrong (what does it mean by 'int' object is not iterable) and how I can fix it.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You are passing a score to check_bust here: `if check_bust(score) == True:` where  you should pass a `hand`

Answer (score 0):

so in your black jack function you have an empty list named hand that is never populated... not to mention when you call score_hand in blackjack hand has nothing so you are trying to call the item in index 0 when there is no item leading to that error...

Comment: You have these two weird lines of code inserted in the middle of the program, score = score_hand(hand); print('  score = ', score). You should define all your functions first, then have the main program at the bottom. And you never instantiate a hand because you never call the blackjack function. Your check_bust looks backwards, bust should be >21 returns True, so as you have it the blackjack function will never deal a card.

Comment: I think you also want to use a while loop in the blackjack function, while check_bust == False and choice == 'h': deal another card, so it continues until the player enters stay or he goes bust.

Answer (score 0):

Given the quantity of semantic and logic errors in this program, I recommend that you adopt the practice of incremental programming: write a few lines, test them, correct the errors, and make sure that much works before you move on.  As it stands, you now have 50 lines of code with some errors masking others, some errors interdependent, and you're now confused as to what went wrong.

Also, learn [basic debugging](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  What worries me most is the amount of time you've likely lost in this process.  Most of all, there should be a meaningful **print** statement just in front of each statement mentioned in your error trace-back, showing the values of applicable variables at time of failure.  That simple technique would have allowed you to find the first few problems, rather than losing time posting this question and waiting for us to respond.

I've made initial repairs to your code:

- Repaired the indentation in **print_hand**
- Repaired various PEP-8 discrepancies (coding style)
- Added the missing call to your entry routine (last line)
- Replaced **score** with **hand** in two calls to **check_bust**
- Removed redundant parts of Boolean checks (e.g. **flag == True**)
- Fixed your attempt to pick a random card (currently line 51).
- Removed the useless **return** at the end of **blackjack**

The program is far from done.  For instance, one branch of **blackjack** returns a Boolean; the others simply return naturally.  That return statement ends the game after dealing the second card.

I leave those up to you; I hope you keep programming.  You've done quite a bit *right* in getting this far.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import random

deck = ['2s', '3s', '4s', '5s', '6s', '7s', '8s', '9s', '10s', 'Js', 'Qs', 'Ks', 'As']  # Set of cards*


def score_hand(hand):   # defines the score of the individual cards and player total*
    score = 0
    for card in hand:
        f = card[0]     # This seems to be where the problem is but I don't understand it*
        if f == 'A':
            if score >= 20:
                score += 1
            else:
                score += 11
        elif f == 'J' or f == 'Q' or f == 'K':
            score += 10
        elif f == '1':
            score += 10
        else:
            score += int(f)
    return score


def print_hand(hand):
    print('cards = ', end=' ')
    for card in hand:
        print(card, end=' ')

    score = score_hand(hand)
    print('  score = ', score)


def check_bust(hand):
    score = score_hand(hand)
    if score <= 21:
        return True
    if score > 21:
        return False


def blackjack():
    hand = []
    score = score_hand(hand)
    choice = 'h'
    if check_bust(hand):
        if choice == 'h':
            card_num = random.randint(0, len(deck)-1)
            card = deck[card_num]
            hand.append(card)
            deck.remove(deck[random.randint(0, len(deck)-1)])
            print_hand(hand)
            choice = raw_input("Enter h for hit or s for stand.")
            return check_bust(hand)
        if choice == 's':
            print('compare with dealer')
    if not check_bust(score):
        print('Bust, score =', score)
        return

blackjack()
```